# If i click on 2nd monitor while gaming on fullscreen, the game closes

Tags: windows-10, fullscreen

The title basically says it all, while I'm gaming, CSGO for example, if I click on something on the second monitor, the game is minimized.
I want to know how I can fix this **WITHOUT** having to put my game on borderless.

Answer (score 1):

from u/Tilimorf on [www.reddit.com/r/Steam/comments/7397c3/game_minimize_when_clicking_on_second_monitor/](https://www.reddit.com/r/Steam/comments/7397c3/game_minimize_when_clicking_on_second_monitor/)

When I have games that have this issue, and setting them to windowed full screen doesn't fix this, or isn't an option. I use Shift+Tab before selecting the second monitor. This isn't really ideal but keeps my game from minimizing.